# С, Количество единиц в двоичной записи отрицательного числа

Tags: c

Мне нужно подсчитать количество единиц в двоичной записи числа. С положительными числами я разобрался, но непонятно, как реализовать алгоритм с отрицательными. Отрицательные числа представляются в дополнительном коде.

```
int bitcount(int n) {
    unsigned int c1 = 0;
    for (; n > 0; n >>= 1)
        if (n & 1) {
            c1++;
        }
    return c1;
    }

int main() {
    int a = -2;
    printf("%u \n", bitcount(a));
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Переводите число в `unsigned`, и вперед...

Comment: [Обзор методов подсчёта количества единиц с измерениями производительности](https://habrahabr.ru/post/276957/). А по поводу отрицательных Harry правильно сказал: нужно лишь привести число в тип unsigned. Таким образом число -1 преобразуется в 0xffffffff, в котором 32 единицы.

Answer (score 2):

```
int bits(unsigned int x)
{
    x = x - ((x >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    x = (x & 0x33333333) + ((x>>2)&0x33333333);
    x = (x + (x >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F;
    x += x >> 8;
    x += x >> 16;
    return x&0x3F;
}

int main()
{
    for(int i = -5; i <= 5; ++i)
        printf("%3d %5d\n",i,bits(i));
}
```

Comment: А нету __builtin_popcount в с? А то нет под рукой компилятора.

Comment: @pavel В стандарте нет и не должно быть, как я понимаю. Уж очень сильная привязка к архитектуре...

Comment: А такой хитрый метод будет работать, если вместо unsigned int будет просто некоторый целый беззнаковый тип?

Comment: @Parket будет (возможно аналогичный). Нужно будет константы подправить.

Comment: @Parket Это - для 32-битного. Для других типов - нужно немного повозиться и переделать. Но это не так уж и сложно...